# Merge [beanstalk], [elastic-beanstalk], and [amazon-elastic-beanstalk] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Elastic Beanstalk seems to have picked up a few tags that could be merged together:

- [beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beanstalk)

> Amazon Elastic Beanstalk is a part of Amazon Web Services (AWS) and
>   allows developers to upload an application and Elastic Beanstalk
>   automatically handles the deployment details of capacity provisioning,
>   load balancing, auto-scaling, and application health monitoring. You
>   can create, manage and deploy your application through a central
>   interface, through a web API or through a console.
>
> This tag is for Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, and should not be confused
>   with beanstalkapp.com which is a git/mercurial hosting app.

- [elastic-beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elastic-beanstalk)

> Elastic Beanstalk is a PAAS cloud service offered by Amazon Web
>   Services. AWS Elastic Beanstalk is an easy-to-use service for
>   deploying and scaling web applications and services developed with
>   popular programming languages such as Java, .NET, PHP, Node.js, Python
>   and Ruby. You simply upload your application and Elastic Beanstalk
>   automatically handles the deployment details of capacity provisioning,
>   load balancing, auto-scaling and application health monitoring. At the
>   same time, with Elastic Beanstalk, you retain full control over the
>   AWS resources powering your application and can access the underlying
>   resources at any time.
>
> One of the easiest ways of uploading your application is to use the
>   command line interface.

- [amazon-elastic-beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-elastic-beanstalk)

> AWS Elastic Beanstalk is a PaaS (Platform as a Service) service from
>   Amazon Web Services that allows users to create applications and push
>   them to a definable set of AWS services. AWS Elastic Beanstalk is a
>   PaaS (Platform as a Service) service from Amazon Web Services that
>   allows users to create applications and push them to a definable set
>   of AWS services, including Amazon EC2, Amazon S3, Amazon Simple
>   Notification Service (SNS), Amazon CloudWatch, auto scaling, and
>   elastic load balancers.

Would it be possible to merge these?

Comment: Hmm, so `amazon-elastic-beanstalk` only has 15 questions tagged with it. Curious, does the tag box autocomplete only alphabetically? i.e if I typed in `beanstalk` and `elastic-beanstalk` is the canonical tag, will it suggest `elastic-beanstalk` ?

Comment: Ok, Yes I just checked  - it does autocomplete

Answer (score 4):

Beanstalk is not Elastic Beanstalk.

Beanstalk is free/paid repository hosting.

Elastic Beanstalk is an AWS PaaS.

The tag for Beanstalk says it's for Amazon's PaaS. But if you look at the [questions for which it was created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beanstalk?page=4&sort=newest&pagesize=50), you see that the tag was created for the repository hosting, with that 'disclaimer' added years after the tag was already in use for something else.

Literally, some dude just decided to start doing that. If you search meta (migrated meta) you find it being brought up but no consensus was reached. Someone just decided to declare it as such.

Before permanently sequestering the Beanstalk tag, there needs to be a definitive discussion about what we're going to do about the Beanstalk repository service.

Comment: It doesn't matter what it was originally created for.  What matters is how people are using it now.  The description of the tag says AWS Beanstalk, and even in your link there are plenty of AWS Beanstalk questions.  Your post adds to the fact that we should fix the issue.  Let's then get a tag for beanstalkapp.com's service and solve the problem.  `beanstalk-svn` and/or `beanstalk-git` maybe?  For what it's worth, I **did** search meta before posting this and didn't find anything.  Got a link so we can mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: It's on the migrated meta (meta.stackexchange.com) so it's not a duplicate anymore.

Comment: [tag:beanstalk] was synonymized after a suggestion by David Levesque on Oct 3 '13 at 16:16 and approved by the community. Here is the [list of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146195/name-collision-on-tag-beanstalk/146197#146197) that are related to the beanstalk repository hosting service. I'll poke around and see if a CM can mass retag those questions, if not, I can manually retag those.